# Questions in the gray area between "code" and "design"

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

In my review work, I - rarely, but sometimes - see questions such as this one:

[Keep a div spaced exactly X amount of pixels away from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466118/keep-a-div-spaced-exactly-x-amount-of-pixels-away-from-another)

when I saw this, I realized "I have no idea whether this is on-topic or not". I mean, it is a problem of writing the appropriate CSS and HTML "code", but it's really about specifying the visual design/layout of a web page.

To generalize from this specific question, however - where does the line run between "coding" and "design" questions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question - or questions like it - manifest their problem in code.  Specifically, they're having issues with ensuring that the CSS for their web page behaves a specific and certain way.

This is *not* a design question because the OP isn't asking about how to improve their design; they're trying to get their CSS to work.

Effectively, think of it like this:

- If the OP is asking about a display issue on a web page *and* has code which can reproduce the issue, then it's fine here.
- If the OP is asking about an esoteric or conceptual issue with web pages, then you *may* want to be a bit more careful about it.